# how to add optional parameter in soap action request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, soap, savon, wash-out

I want to add optional paramteter in soap_action(wash_out) request, here is the code

```
soap_action "DeActivate_VAS_Request",
:args => {:some_arguments}, :return => {:return_values}
```

and operation is

```
<operation name="DeActivate_VAS_Request">
   <soap:operation soapAction="DeActivate_VAS_Request"/>
     <input>
       <soap:body
             use="encoded"
             encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
             namespace="urn:WashOut"/>
     </input>
   <output>
     <soap:body use="encoded"
                encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
                namespace="urn:WashOut"/>
   </output>
 </operation>
```

action should be optional, kindly help.

Comment: Could you please clarify you question? I did not get that clearly. It seems you are using savon. What did you try actually?

Comment: I'm using savon for soap. I want to use the soap api for given operation to be optional.

Comment: here is the request

       <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <faultcode xsi:type="xsd:QName">Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring xsi:type="xsd:string">Cannot find SOAP action mapping for</faultstring>
      </soap:Fault>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

Comment: then what do you mean by optional parameter?

Comment: got the solution. there was no support for soap_action in wash_out gem  v 0.5.2. I have update the gem now everything seems to be working fine. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can monkey patch wash_out 0.5.2. Put this in `config/initializers/washout_monkey_patch.rb`

```
WashOut::Param.class_eval do
    attr_accessor :optional

    def initialize(name, type, multiplied = false, optional = false)
      type ||= {}

      @name       = name.to_s
      @raw_name   = name.to_s
      @map        = {}
      @multiplied = multiplied
      @optional   = optional

      if WashOut::Engine.camelize_wsdl.to_s == 'lower'
        @name = @name.camelize(:lower)
      elsif WashOut::Engine.camelize_wsdl
        @name = @name.camelize
      end

      if type.is_a?(Symbol)
        @type = type.to_s
      elsif type.is_a?(Class)
        @type         = 'struct'
        @map          = self.class.parse_def(type.wash_out_param_map)
        @source_class = type
      else
        @type = 'struct'
        @map  = self.class.parse_def(type)
      end
    end

    def flat_copy
      copy = self.class.new(@name, @type.to_sym, @multiplied, @optional)
      copy.raw_name = raw_name
      copy
    end
end

WashOutHelper.module_eval do
  def wsdl_occurence(param, inject, extend_with = {})
    if param.multiplied
      data = {
        "#{'xsi:' if inject}minOccurs" => 0,
        "#{'xsi:' if inject}maxOccurs" => 'unbounded'
      }
    elsif param.optional
      data = {
        "#{'xsi:' if inject}minOccurs" => 0,
      }
    else
      data = {}
    end

    extend_with.merge(data)
  end

  def wsdl_data(xml, params)
    Rails.logger.debug params
    params.each do |param|
      tag_name = param.name

      if !param.struct?
        if param.multiplied
          param.value = [] unless param.value.is_a?(Array)
          param.value.each do |v|
            xml.tag! tag_name, v, "xsi:type" => param.namespaced_type
          end
        elsif param.optional
          if !param.value.nil?
            xml.tag! tag_name, param.value, "xsi:type" => param.namespaced_type
          end
        else
          xml.tag! tag_name, param.value, "xsi:type" => param.namespaced_type
        end
      else
        if param.multiplied
          param.map.each do |p|
            xml.tag! tag_name, "xsi:type" => param.namespaced_type do
              wsdl_data(xml, p.map)
            end
          end
        elsif param.optional
          if !param.map.empty?
              xml.tag! tag_name, "xsi:type" => param.namespaced_type do
                wsdl_data(xml, param.map)
              end
          end
        else
          xml.tag! tag_name, "xsi:type" => param.namespaced_type do
            wsdl_data(xml, param.map)
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

To define an optional parameter, use the WashOut::Param constructor, passing a third parameter equal to `false`, and a fourth parameter equal to `true`. In the following example, the third input parameter and the second output parameter will be defined to be optional:

```
  soap_action "YourWebService", 
    :args => {
      :arg1    => :string,
      :arg2   => :string,
      :arg3  => WashOut::Param.new(:arg3, :string, false, true),
    },
    :return => {
      :arg1 => :string,
      :arg2 => WashOut::Param.new(:arg2, :string, false, true),
    },
    :to     => :web_service
```